# How to add a date picker (calender) in LiveCode?

Tags: livecode

I would like to add a date picker. When a user clicks on the textbox a Calender should open. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

I use "calendarPane" from Rotunda.

http://www.rotundasoftware.com/livecode/calendarPane.php

Craig Newman

Answer (score 0):

If you are on mobile you can use mobilePickDate to invoke the native date picker for iOS or Android. On the desktop, there several 3rd party calendar options, including the well regarded DatePicker from FlexibleLearning.com